# Reduced CPU uses in Java application

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, cpu-usage

I have an Application in java and when i runs it in IDE of even in Desktop that is consuming much cpu because of that my pc hangs and I am not able to work even. so is there any way that I can reduced that application uses CUP never about 20 to 30 instead of 101 or 100 see Screen shot.![enter image description here][1]

can any body tell me how it is possible?

Comment: I can tell you one way it's possible: `while (true);` - but to see how your program is doing it, we'd have to be able to see your program.

Comment: @ChrisMartin i did not get u. what it will make?

Comment: How is the percent over 100, so weird?

Comment: @Octopus reporting of multicore CPU

Comment: @Octopus yes bro it is because its hanging pc and not able to work even afte that. :(

Comment: @Krishna so it is now time to optimize your code.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood its possible to reduce it because code is much big i can not devide it.

Comment: @user3580294 if u can not do let it be. :D haha

Comment: @Krishna Do you have some while(true) loops in your code? Are you working with IO's? Pls show us the code. Cant hardly help you without it.

Comment: @RaphMclee bro its more then 22000 line code how could i show it and even it is confidential. and ya i do have that loops there.

Comment: To answer your original question, I don't believe it is possible to limit CPU usage from inside Java itself. You're going to have to change your code.

Comment: @Krishna What about lowering the process prio? http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/

Comment: @user3580294 it is possible dude.

Comment: @RaphMclee thanks for suggestion dude m looking at it :)

Comment: @Krishna I don't think it's possible to do so *from within Java*. It's certainly possible by manipulating thread priorities (or by working around the issue, such as by sleeping periodically), but those don't seem to be answers you're looking for.

Comment: Over zealous use of thread and or `repaint`. An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer welcome again bro and ya i am seeing that link.

Comment: Changing the priority will allow other processes to run when they need to, but it won't do much to curtail the overall processor usage of your program.

Comment: @ChrisMartin well its true. its would be same. is it? @MadProgrammer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to identify where your bottleneck in your program is, and then control how much of the time your application is idle by sleeping your thread(s) that is working. Let's say that you have identified your bottleneck and that it's a loop. Then you can measure the time it takes to compute one iteration in your loop. After you have this number you simply calculate how long you want your processor to sleep based on the percentage you want your application to be idle.

For example, lets say that you want your application to only use 20% of your processor, and it takes 20 ms to complete one iteration in your loop. Then you want to sleep 80 ms in the end of your loop before the next iteration to make the processor go idle 80% of the time. If you don't have a "gameloop" or similar this can be a bit harder to achieve, but at least you can try to approximate how much time to sleep to not make it work at 100%

Comment: Welll not wrong suggestion but. do i have to go throw all code again? for that?

Comment: No, you don't have to throw any code away. You look at your code, identify your bottleneck, measure its time, and then sleep according to the calculations i mentioned. Keep all your code, just add a part at the end where your processor sleeps for a while

Comment: i am putting most of code in thread it self. some of the code is there which is all time have to run in background

Comment: Yes, and in that thread, you just tell it to sleep. Use this: http://goo.gl/xZWvp0

Comment: but still it will be waited for execution na.